# Default Value Expression for Optional String Input iReport

Tags: postgresql, jasper-reports

I'm using `PostgreSQL` as DBMS, in my current report I need an optional String parameter to get records by `Id`, which is a `String` field.

So I set the Default Value Expression to:

```
($P{Param} == null || $P{Param}.equals("")) ? "" : "AND id='" + $P{Param} + "'"
```

When the field is empty the report is created without issues, but when I enter a valid Id the compiler complains:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "160E0"   Position: 3126
```

Just like if I was adding double quotes after and before the value I'm passing. Somebody know how to handle this problem when using String values?

Comment: What report engine are you using?  I can't tell what part of the syntax is from the report definition, and which is from PostgreSQL.

Comment: @KirkRoybal I'm using Jasper Reports, The first snippet is used in iReports and the second part is the log when I'm trying to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you've created one Parameter, named Param and in your query you have **$P!{Param}**. Thing is, default value is set only when parameter stays NULL after prompting, so when you input your ID, **${Param}** value is passed into query as it was inputed by user (**without** AND id=' part).

---

Try creating second parameter, lets name it **$P{input}**; set its default value to your expression, "Use as a prompt" value to false. Pass it to your query (**$P!{input}**). Now, you have your **${Param}** for prompting and when it's value is set to the desired ID, **$P{input}** is set to your query condition.